Book involving Route 66 with a girl breaking her grandma's friends out of a retirement home
I read a book around 2006 to 2008 and I believe it was considered new at the time.
I remember it being called Route 66 with a red convertible on the cover headed towards the open road but whenever I've tried looking for this I can't find it.
I remember the girl hanging out with her grandma over spring break and she meets this guy who comes with them on a trip through route 66 when the grandma has the girl make a pit stop and she has to bust her grandma's friends out of these retirement homes.

Is it any of these?

This sounds a lot like The Road to Me by Laura Drake, but it was only published in 2022, and doesn't have a red convertible on the cover.

Also sounds like The Summer Seekers by Sarah Morgan, but it was also published recently.  (Does have a red convertible on the cover, though...)
